# Connect to VPN without Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

My college offers a VPN service to connect to the campus network via the AnyConnect client from Cisco.

Since I don't like to install proprietary software for a functionality that pretty much every operating system offers at this point, I was wondering if I can get around installing the AnyConnect client.

From what I found out, my college is using Cisco IPsec. For my operating system to connect it needs a shared secret or a certificate and a group name. Since the AnyConnect client doesn't ask for these details, I don't know them but the Cisco software obviously needs to figure them out by itself.

My question now is, (how) can I find out these details? Would it be possible to run the AnyConnect client and then read out the connection details?

Comment: The older Cisco VPN clients (prior to "AnyConnect") used *.vcf config files for each connection.  You can see  the encrypted shared secret in that file, and run it thru a decryptor (easily found on the web) to get the original secret word/phrase.  AnyConnect does not use the same VCF files, and I haven't found any way to see the shared secret yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I had found [`openconnect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenConnect) which is open source and a replacement for the proprietary client from Cisco. It's not perfect but worked fine for my use.